# How to display for each digit, starting with the most significant, whether it is odd or even

Tags: c#, math

I am like 2 weeks new to C# or coding overall and I am trying to figure out the following:

> Write a console application that displays for each digit, starting with the most significant, whether it is odd or even.

For input data:

`5228`

The console will display:

```
ODD
EVEN
EVEN
EVEN
```

When running my code I get:

```
EVEN
EVEN
EVEN
ODD
```

Can you help me start from the most significant digit?

This is my current implementation:

```
using System;
public class TestVariablesandExpressions
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string inputData = Console.ReadLine();
        int num = Convert.ToInt32(inputData);
        int reverse = 0;

        while (num > 0)
        {
            reverse = reverse * 10 + num % 10;
            num /= 10;

      

            if (reverse % 2 == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("EVEN");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ODD");
            }
        }      
    }
}
```

Comment: Modulo 10 returns the *last* digit, not the first. Your code is checking digits from the end

Comment: You shouldn't remove the code from the question because it's incorrect. That's the whole point of it being in a question and not an answer.

Comment: You could just process the number as a string !

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but you can't solve the task with you current *reverse* implementation: the *counter example* is when `num` ends with `0`:

```
num == 12000 => (reverse) => 00012 == 12 => "ODD EVEN"
```

Another problem which is in you current code is a potential *integer overflow*: no `int` value can be greater than `int.MaxValue = 2147483647`, but if `num` ends with `2..9` the reversed value can exceed the `int.MaxValue`:

```
1000000009 => (reverse) => 9000000001 => (overflow) == 410065409 
(or something else depending on reverse implementation)
```

But you can *preserve* trailing zeroes and forget about overflow by using `string` instead of `int`. The only potential problem is *negative* numbers where we should *skip* `-` (`-123 => ODD EVEN ODD`).

```
int num = ...

string text = num.ToString(); 

for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; ++i)
  if (text[i] >= '0' && text[i] <= '9') { // In case we have negative numbers
    if ((text[i] - '0') % 2 == 0) // Note, that text[i] is char, not int
      Console.WriteLine("EVEN");
    else
      Console.WriteLine("ODD");
  }
```

**Edit:** If you don't want `string` at all you have to deal with more elaborated code:

First, let's enumerate digits:

```
private static IEnumerable<int> Digits(int value) {
  if (value == 0)
    yield return value; // Single 0 is a special case
  else
    for (; value != 0; value /= 10)
      yield return Math.Abs(value % 10);
}
```

Then we can `Reverse` the sequence with a help of *Linq*:

```
using System.Linq;

...

static void Main(string[] args) {
  int num = ...

  foreach (int digit in Digits(num).Reverse())
    if (digit % 2 == 0)
      Console.WriteLine("EVEN");
    else
      Console.WriteLine("ODD");

  ...
}
```

Comment: Technically you could omit the `- '0'` part because it so happens that the UTF8 code for each digit is even if the digit is even, and odd if the digit is odd.

Comment: @Matthew Watson: I see, but I wanted to stress the difference between *char* `'0'` with its ascii code (`48`) and corresponding `int` *digit* `0`. Here we can omit `- '0'`, but it's just a coincidence, let's show the correct technique.

Answer (score 0):

One-liner:

```
foreach (char c in Console.ReadLine()) Console.WriteLine((c & 1) == 0 ? "EVEN" : "ODD");
```

Alternatively,

```
string[] Parity= { "EVEN", "ODD"};
foreach (char c in Console.ReadLine()) Console.WriteLine(Parity[c & 1]);
```

This code will accept non-digit characters and leading zeroes, but you didn't specify anything about this.

Comment: Probably, `"0123"` is a *counter example*: leading `0` is not *the most significant digit* (as it's specified in the question) but it well be taken into account and we'll get `EVEN ODD EVEN ODD` instead of expected `ODD EVEN ODD`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko: that's right. As you see, this version is lazy on checks. A Q&D way to cope is to convert to int then back to string. But we can also assume that the OP meant *leftmost* rather than *most significant*. :-)

Comment: Yes, `int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()).ToString()` will cure `"0123"`, but we still want to add `.Trim('-')` or something to deal with negative numbers ;)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko: by the way, what should the output be for input "0" ?

Comment: My *guess* that `"000" => 000 == 0 => EVEN` Same for `"0"`: `"0" => 0 => EVEN`